# Extracting Baldur's Gate II Sounds (not music)

Tags: baldurs-gate, baldurs-gate-2

I have the original Baldur's Gate I, II and the Throne of Baal expansion (as well as Icewind Dale) but I was interested in a few sounds from BGII, more specifically the casting sounds of mages.

This is just for fun and personal use and zero commercial interest.

Does anyone know of a method or a place were I could find them or extract them from the original media?

Comment: I actually used some sounds from BG1 in a music project a long time ago. I seem to remember there were .wav files in a 'sounds' or 'resources' folder under the installed tree. I wouldn't be surprised if BG2 had a similar setup, but I'm not sure, so leaving this for someone more authoritative to answer.

Comment: Definitely not the case with BG2, the audio is stored in a non-standard format.

Answer (score 3):

You can find and extract the audio resources used in the game to wav format using the [Game Audio Player (GAP)](http://www.fileplanet.com/164521/160000/fileinfo/Game-Audio-Player). I can't test this for myself now, but forum posts on other websites suggest that this program works with Baldur's Gate games.

Comment: Will give it a try. Thanks. Will wait to see if anyone has something else to add otherwise your answer will be ;)